# Why is the event on an element not triggered even when the element exists in the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added a click event to an element but the event is not firing when I click on it.
If I try to get the HTML content of the particular element and display in console, it shows it there which means the element exists but when I now click on the element, the event added to it is not being triggered sort of like its not defined when clicked. This is my HTML code below

````
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Su`rveillance Camera | Admin Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
    
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="esp_module/css/admin_home.css">
 
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha512-5A8nwdMOWrSz20fDsjczgUidUBR8liPYU+WymTZP1lmY9G6Oc7HlZv156XqnsgNUzTyMefFTcsFH/tnJE/+xBg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
 
 
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
 
    
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script> 
  
   <script src=" https://unpkg.com/micromodal/dist/micromodal.min.js"></scri      
  </head>
  
  
  <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
     
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   
  //ADD USER     
const btn = document.querySelector("#open_add_user");
   
 btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
   alert("clicked)  
document.querySelector(".add-user-form").style.display="block";

});   
    
})     
     
 </script>
 
 
 
 
<!-- Add User modal--> 

<div class="mod">
    
<div class="container add-user-form dn">
    
<div class="box">
    
<div class="container is-fluid">
    
 <p class="title is-4">Add User</p>
 <hr>
    
    <p class="mb-3">Enter the email and password of the user u wish to add and press add</p>
   <hr>
  <div class="columns is-mobilee">
      
   <div class="column is-full-mobile">
 <input class="input is-primary" type="email" placeholder="User Email" required>      
   </div> 
      
  <div class="column is-full-mobile">
       
   <input class="input is-primary" type="password" placeholder="User Email" required>   
      
  </div> 
     
  <div class="column is-one-fifth-mobile">
       
   <button class="button is-primary add-user-btn">Add</button>
      
  </div> 
      
    
    
</div>    
    
    
</div>   
    
</div>  
 
 </div>
 </div>
      
 
 <!--Menu section-->
 <section>
     
     
 <div class="container is-fluidd">
     
<div style="display:flex; flex-flow:row wrap;" class="columns is-mobile ">
 
 <div  class="column is-half-mobile ">
     
  <div id="open_add_user" class="box open_add_user">
      
      
  <p class=""><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Add User</p>    
      
  </div> 
     
 </div>
    
  <div class="column is-half-mobile">
     
  <div class="box">
      
      
  <p><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Remove User</p>    
      
  </div> 
     
 </div>  
 
 
 <div class="column is-half-mobile">
     
  <div class="box">
      
      
  <p><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Edit User</p>    
      
  </div> 
  
  
  
     
 </div>  
   
    <div class="column is-half-mobile">
     
  <div class="box">
      
      
  <p><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>Change Admin Number</p>    
      
  </div> 
     
 </div>  
</div>  
     
 </div>   
     
 </section> 

  
  </body>
</html>```



I have spent some time trying to figure what's wrong to no avail. Thanks in advance


I tried to log `$("#open_add_user").html();` into console and it shows the HTML content of it. Which shows it exists in the DOM.

I also tried to use const chk = $("#open_add_user").length;
````

Comment: Well closing a script tag with `</scri` might be an issue.

Comment: You're also missing a quote. `alert("clicked)` should be `alert("clicked");`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: While we’re at it, bootstrap has to be loaded after jQuery.